# Excel vba: find value in another sheet

Tags: excel, search, vba

I am trying to find a value from sheet1 in `sheet2(A1:DF5000)`. The problem is the value can be anywhere in sheet2. One more thing once it finds a match; lets say in `sheet2 X495` I need it to return value of `sheet2 X1`.

1. Always return column from search match
2. Always return row 1
3. Always use Exact match

So if I was searching for "ABC" and a exact match was found in `sheet2!D14`. It would return the value `Sheet2!D1`.

Real world application:

I am using excel to keep track of all my sku's I use for products. each site requires a unique sku. so I have hundreds of sku's that are all the same product. so i have a master list in excel with row 1 as my product's then each column has all the sku's used for each product

This code below was working but had some funny things happening. Turns out it is not searching for exact match but it's close.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Also feel free to ask me any questions if I was not clear.

```
Function GetPart(text As Variant, rCells As Range)
  Dim txt As String
  Dim rRange As Range
  Dim SubjCell

  For Each rRange In rCells
    SubjCell = rRange
    txt = text

    If InStr(txt, SubjCell) <> 0 Then
      GetPart = SubjCell
      Exit For
    Else
      GetPart = "Not Found"
    End If
  Next rRange

End Function
```

Comment: See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) Section 4

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Section 5 is working great, Do you know how to then return the value of result column row 1?

Comment: `Cells(1, aCell.Column).Value`? Where `aCell` is the cell where you found the match...

Comment: i have been trying for a few weeks to get "Cells(1, aCell.Column).Value? Where aCell" to work. I really appreciate your answer and wanted to figure it out on my own. But i  just can't manage to get it to work. Where do i put the " Cells(1, aCell.Column).Value? Where aCell"?

Thank You.

Comment: oh also this is important. my sku it uses to search with is 10AAAMBMFCFf92304924 in the master sheet of the hundreds of sku's one is 0AAAMB and another is 10AAAMB.    This search returns the 0AAAMB when it should return  the 10AAAMB.  the "10AAAMBMFCFf92304924" is in F485 the sku to return is in F1. 0AAAMB is in E1(this is hte cell it returns) if i move 0AAAMB to a farther out column it then returns the correct sku. But if say the search for sku is B99-3234-2349-a then it will not find a sku at all. There must be an error in my search type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so that you will not have any problem understanding it :) Still if you do then let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetPart(rng As Range, rngDB As Range) As Variant
    Dim aCell As Range, strSearch as String

    GetPart = 0

    On Error GoTo Whoa:

    '~~> This is the value which we will search
    strSearch = rng.Value

    '~~> Notice the use of LookAt:=xlWhole. This is to ensure that we
    '~~> do not get False Positives. Using INSTR will give you False
    '~~> Positives. For example searching for "Coke" in "DigitalCoke"
    Set aCell = rngDB.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> If the match is found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Get value from the first row
        GetPart = aCell.Offset(-(aCell.Row - 1))
    End If

    Exit Function

Whoa:
End Function
```